# windows phone app update xap file

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have successfully published an app on windows phone store without any problem but when i try to publish an update of the xap file i had some problem.

- First I don't understand if have to replace the xap file or add new xap file with higher version number.
- Second, if I update the version number in the app manifest and upload the app in developer console, the version number is always 1.0.0.0. It's a bug or is normal?

I tried to add a new xap with higher version number but when a user with installed app receive the update the app crash on startup, but the app works if is installed from scratch.

Developer console is very confusing for me, I never had problems with android developer dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you have a little guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj631569%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - if you hadn't seen that before. [Here is also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442301%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) a documentation about updating process.

From my experience it goes like this:

- when you click Update, then the new submission is started
- you choose there to replace your XAP file with the new compiled one - don't worry it won't delete old file unless new passes certification and you choose to publish it (watch out for automatic mode)
- you modify the version number at this website, (this numer is used only for Store purposes), if you change the number before replacing the XAP file, the number will be old again (probably page reload).
- your 'InApp' version number is taken from AssemblyInfo.cs (or in Project Properties) in your App. You should also change version number in WMAppManifest.xml -> Packaging
- you should use 'Add new XAP' file if you want to make the App to run on different OS versions
- be aware that files on IsolatedSorage are preserved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to replace the xap file, any idea why the updated app doesn't work but installing it from scratch work? Is something related to the version number or is just because i added new xap instead replacing the existing one? I'm pretty sure it's not an error in the application code...

Comment: @user3382831 You have added a new XAP file for the same OS (WP 8)? And you get the same link as for the old XAP file or different? Look that in this situation there is a problem which file user should download (or Store choose as default), that's why you should use Replace. I advise to test this procedurę as Beta (it's faster) when you get it it is easy (you can add yourself as Beta tester).

Comment: @user3382831 Are you preserving some data from old release? For example if it was installed before or something different?

Comment: I added new xap for the same OS and i have the same link as for the old xap. Also i'm not preserving any data from old release, so if you download the app from scratch or by updating it nothing change.

Comment: @user3382831 I haven't tried with two XAP files for the same OS, in my opinion it can result in problems I've mentioned above. I strongly recommend you to play with Beta evrsion (within few hours you will know everything). I've added second link in answer with some more information.

Comment: @Romasz Can you please look on to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160224/will-windows-phone-appdata-change-deleted-if-i-update-aapx-file-with-xap-in-to ?