# Update app in windowsphone store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I publish app in WPStore.
I want update app now.

1. Add update
2. Upload new xap

1 problem - new xap version 1.0.0.0 (old) but new version xap is 1.1.0.0

2 problem - all tags, description, keyword on all languages is empy. How copy from previous version?

Comment: Did you use "replace" or "add new"?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22195940/2681948) will help.

Comment: Store - MyApp - Update app - Upload and describe your XAP(s) - add new (lost description). Replace - version incorrect

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov When you choose to replace XAP file all other information is preserved

Comment: Yes, thanks. Use Replace and modify version.

Comment: Have you changed the version in both WMAppManifest and assemblyinfo.cs?

Comment: Yes, in both WMAppManifest and assemblyinfo.cs (1.1.0.0). But WPStore show old version 1.0.0.0

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov WPStore version is independent and is not loaded from your XAP, you have to change it manually after you repleace the file and it will change after you submit the update.