# Will Windows Phone AppData change/Deleted if I update.aapx file with .xap in to the store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I created an universal Windows Phone application using c# xaml that have user information in the appdata '`Local`' folder.

And I published it in to store. But due to some performance issue I forced to move on to `silverlight` for updating the application.

So I need to update package `.appx` file with `.xap` file. 
Is that possible ? Will it delete data from Local app folder of the current user ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will be possible. The appx stands for a bundle, I don't know is Store will accept 'going down' to xap file. The best would be here to test it with beta app - it will take you couple of hours of waiting but at least you will be 100% sure.

Comment: So what about updating a universal windows phone app ".appx" file with silverlight windows phone app ".appx" file ?

Comment: Again - not sure - check it with beta store app.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this, but I don't think they are compatible. I expect that the store will remove the appx project entirely and mark it as "Removed from store" or something. The the xap version will be an entire separate app  and your users will have to manually download the app from the store to get it. After this they will have two apps with the same name on their phones. Never mind the Local folder being deleted, I don't think it will even use the same directory.